# hostapd: mapping MAC address to VLAN ID (static mapping via accept_mac_file)

Tags: linux, vlan, mac-address, access-point, hostapd

**I want hostapd to assign each station a given VLAN based on MAC address**. BTW, my network is quite small. Using RADIUS would be an overkill.

According to the [hostapd manual](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf):

> Optionally, the local MAC ACL list (accept_mac_file) can be used to
>   set static client MAC address to VLAN ID mapping.

Let's assume I only have 1 station (with MAC DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE). I've created a VLAN using:

```
sudo ip link add link wlan0 name vlan.100 type vlan id 100
sudo ip addr add 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 dev vlan.100
sudo ip link set dev vlan.100 up
```

On hostapd.conf I'm using:

```
#  Interface to use
interface=wlan0
#  Driver
driver=nl80211
#  Name of the network
ssid=YaddaYadda
#  Use the 2.4GHz band: g = IEEE 802.11g (2.4 GHz)
hw_mode=g
#  Use channel 6
channel=6
#  Enable 802.11n
ieee80211n=1
#  Enable 40MHz channels with 20ns guard interval
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
#  Accept only known MAC addresses
macaddr_acl=1
accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/accept
#  Use WPA authentication
auth_algs=1
#  Send empty SSID in beacons and ignore probe request frames that do not specify full SSID
ignore_broadcast_ssid=1
#  Use WPA2
wpa=2
#  Use a pre-shared key
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
#  Enable the wireless multimedia extensions
wmm_enabled=1
#  The network hashed passphrase
wpa_psk=786451648446NotReallyTheHashedPassphrase849989654651651651654564
#  Use AES, instead of TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
# Isolate Clients
ap_isolate=1

#  HOSTAPD event logger configuration
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2

#  Country code
country_code=NO
```

On file */etc/hostapd/accept* I have included the following:

```
DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE vlan.100
```

hostapd starts without any issues. However, after connecting my station with MAC DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE, I'm still getting all the traffic on wlan0 and not on vlan.100...

hostapd does not say much about how the file accept_mac_file should look like to map MAC <-> VLAN ID. I've tried comma, with and without spaces, but no luck...

Has anyone been able to get this MAC <-> VLAN mapping to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [`hostapd` source code](https://w1.fi/cvs.html), I find that there is a [`hostapd_config_read_maclist()` function](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/hostapd/config_file.c?id=29c832d0ea4fdac45e8433c1d4e84791f5e640c3#n173) in `config_file.c` that parses the files referenced by the [`accept_mac_file`](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/hostapd/config_file.c?id=29c832d0ea4fdac45e8433c1d4e84791f5e640c3#n2528) and [`deny_mac_file`](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/hostapd/config_file.c?id=29c832d0ea4fdac45e8433c1d4e84791f5e640c3#n2535) configuration values:

```c
static int hostapd_config_read_maclist(const char *fname,
                       struct mac_acl_entry **acl, int *num)
{
    FILE *f;
    char buf[128], *pos;
    int line = 0;
    u8 addr[ETH_ALEN];
    int vlan_id;

    f = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (!f) {
        wpa_printf(MSG_ERROR, "MAC list file '%s' not found.", fname);
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) {
        int rem = 0;

        line++;

        if (buf[0] == '#')
            continue;
        pos = buf;
        while (*pos != '\0') {
            if (*pos == '\n') {
                *pos = '\0';
                break;
            }
            pos++;
        }
        if (buf[0] == '\0')
            continue;
        pos = buf;
        if (buf[0] == '-') {
            rem = 1;
            pos++;
        }

        if (hwaddr_aton(pos, addr)) {
            wpa_printf(MSG_ERROR, "Invalid MAC address '%s' at "
                   "line %d in '%s'", pos, line, fname);
            fclose(f);
            return -1;
        }

        if (rem) {
            hostapd_remove_acl_mac(acl, num, addr);
            continue;
        }
        vlan_id = 0;
        pos = buf;
        while (*pos != '\0' && *pos != ' ' && *pos != '\t')
            pos++;
        while (*pos == ' ' || *pos == '\t')
            pos++;
        if (*pos != '\0')
            vlan_id = atoi(pos);

        if (hostapd_add_acl_maclist(acl, num, vlan_id, addr) < 0) {
            fclose(f);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

    if (*acl)
        qsort(*acl, *num, sizeof(**acl), hostapd_acl_comp);

    return 0;
}
```

I haven't (yet) tested this to confirm, but based on the code above, it looks like the rules for `*_mac_file` files are as follows:

1. Lines beginning with `#` are ignored.
2. Empty lines are ignored.
3. A MAC address is specified by six octets in hexadecimal, each separated by `:`.

- A MAC address can optionally be prefixed with `-` to remove all occurrences of it from the list thus far.
- Otherwise, a MAC address can optionally be followed by some combination of space and tab characters followed by an integer specifying the VLAN.  If the VLAN is `0`, not specified, or not an integer this is treated as no VLAN.

Based on these rules, I believe the way to map the MAC address `DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE` to the VLAN with name `vlan.100` and ID `100` is with this line:

```
DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE 100
```

That is, only the VLAN ID matters to `hostapd`, not the VLAN name.