# hostapd: assigning static sub-IP based on MAC

Tags: ip, hostapd

I've set up an access point / wifi-repeater via hostapd on my raspberry pi using [this incredible tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803).

Now I want to ensure that the connecting clients have a "static" IP in the subnet.
Example:

- Client with MAC `0d:78:b9:5c:1d:b6` connects to the AP.
- The client is assigned the IP `192.168.4.200`

How can I ensure that the assigned sub-IP (`.200`) is *always* the same?
Will it change randomly after a few connections? Can I somehow map specific IPs to the connecting MACs?

I've read about [`accept_mac_file` and `VLAN`](https://serverfault.com/questions/937595), but I am unsure if this solves my issue.

Comment: I thought that you would generally set up a DHCP server (like [dnsmasq](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)) to handle address assignment when using hostapd. Tjen you would just add static host entries to your DHCP server configuration. E.g., based on the instructions in [this article](https://hawksites.newpaltz.edu/myerse/2018/06/08/hostapd-on-raspberry-pi/) and the following one [here](https://hawksites.newpaltz.edu/myerse/2018/06/19/dhcp-daemon-on-raspberry-pi/) (that article uses the ISC DHCP Server; I would suggest sticking with dnsmasq in most cases because it's simpler).

Comment: @larsks thanks for the idea, I will give it a try. But `dnsmasq` has previously bricked my configuration, so I will use caution, still searching for a solution with `hostapd` only.